# Python 3.X Robot Framework: Library To Use to push SOAP Request To Services/Listener

Tags: robotframework

I am trying to learn about any library which is good to use with Python 3.X where Script can send the SOAP/XML request to Listener/Services and Capture the response. 
HttpLibrary.HTTP cant work with python 3. similar case with JASONLibrary. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I used "suds" library to send SOAP requests and it worked fine.
Please give it a try. The instructions are in the below link

[Python3-Suds](https://github.com/cackharot/suds-py3)

Also check the Robot Suds library
[Robot-Suds](http://ombre42.github.io/robotframework-sudslibrary/doc/SudsLibrary.html)